# .abc (Alembic) 3d model with animation won't play in SceneKit preview

Tags: scenekit, blender, collada, alembic, cinema-4d

I have been able to get models from .dae (COLLADA) files with animation working in the SceneKit preview (which is the best way I know to test if an animation is compatible).

I have a freelancer who made an animation for me originally in Cinema 4D, used a plugin to help with the animation, and exported it to me in .abc. He says he thinks the animations get lost when trying .dae format.

When I import his .abc file into Blender, it plays the animation perfectly, but importing into Xcode/SceneKit (whether I try to play it as a .abc file or after converting it to .scn) won't play the file. You can at best just see the initial positioning of the 3D model and no animation will play.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: Nope. Using animations in SceneKit is my least favorite activity thus far

Comment: I have the same problem.